# Partial derivatives, functions and coming back to the given function.

Tags: calculus

I was interested in solving this particular problem. It goes like this:

If $u= \frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}$, show that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u$.

I got an answer of $(x+y)\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}$, which is almost close  to the given function $u= \frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}$. I don't know were I got wrong.

How will I properly verify the given statement above?

Comment: To be honest, it would be a **lot easier** for us to tell where you went wrong if you show us all the steps you took to get to that answer.

Comment: I put my answer as my version of the solution, hehe......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using law of exponents:

$$u=\frac{e^xe^y}{e^x+e^y}$$

Differentiating:

$$u_x=\frac{(e^xe^y)\cdot(e^x+e^y)-(e^xe^y)\cdot(e^x)}{(e^x+e^y)^2}=\frac{(e^xe^y)\cdot e^y}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$$

$$u_y=\frac{(e^xe^y)\cdot(e^x+e^y)-(e^xe^y)\cdot(e^y)}{e^x+e^y}=\frac{(e^xe^y)\cdot e^x}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$$

Adding and Simplifying:

$$u_x+u_y=\frac{e^xe^{2y}+e^{2x}e^y}{(e^x+e^y)^2}=\frac{e^{x+y}(e^x+e^y)}{(e^x+e^y)^2}=\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}=u$$

Answer (score 1):

I got something different from you, so maybe your derivatives are wrong.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{e^{x+2y}}{(e^x + e^y)^2}$$

And similarly

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{e^{2x+y}}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$$

So the sum is $$\frac{e^{x+y}(e^y+e^x)}{(e^x+e^y)^2} $$

Which is obviously the same as $u$.

Perhaps you accidentally applied the chain rule where it wasn't appropriate?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7Bx%2By%7D%2F(e%5Ex+%2B+e%5Ey)  The derivative is as I put it here.

Comment: You have combined the terms ... I would have done the differentiation a little slower so the OP could workout where they have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I arrived at my answer.

Given the function $$u= \frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}$$ and showing that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u,$$ first, I need to get the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Getting now the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$:

Recall that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u}{v})=\frac{v du-u dv}{v^2}$ (maybe it's applicable to partial derivatives too, which is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{u}{v})$? hehe), then

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}) = \frac{[(e^x+e^y)*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\frac{e^{x+y}}{1})]-[(e^{x+y})*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\frac{e^x+e^y}{1})]}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$$. Getting some things tidy, we get

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{ye^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}.$$

Getting now the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$:

Recall that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u}{v})=\frac{v du-u dv}{v^2}$, then

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}) = \frac{[(e^x+e^y)*\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\frac{e^{x+y}}{1})]-[(e^{x+y})*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\frac{e^x+e^y}{1})]}{(e^x+e^y)^2}$$. Getting some things tidy, we get

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{xe^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}.$$

Then by doing this: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $, I get the answer $$(x+y)\frac{e^{x+y}}{e^x+e^y}$$

Where did I got it wrong?